# Bootstrap Hovering

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to do simply on bootstrap framework the following thing?

Example having a few buttons and when one is hovered the others change to light grey or something. Sorry but I can't find it on w3 schools or in the web.

Should javascript be used?

Thanks!

Comment: No it's not possible. Use your own javascript code to do so. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible without javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/ap8vT/284/

```
.wrapper:hover .default {
    opacity: .5;   
}
.wrapper .default:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

You can define those styles whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery to do functionality

HTML

```
<button class="default">Default</button>
<button class="default">Submit</button>
<button class="default">Delete</button>
<button class="default">Blue Pill</button>

</div>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").mouseenter(function(e){
        $("button").each(function(){
            if($(e.target).text() != $(this).text()){ 
        $(this).addClass('defaulta');
            }
        });

    });
    $("button").mouseleave(function(){
        $("button").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('defaulta');
        });

    });
});
```

[**JS FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/ap8vT/283/)

Comment: good answer thanks! but I think it would be better to go with simple css on this one :D